# Convert vector of arrays into vector of vectors c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I need a way to convert data in the form of `std::vector<std::array<int, 2> >` into `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`
quickly. 
I have the following solution, but on large vectors this is quite slow for me.

```cpp
std::vector<std::array<int, 2> > data; // filled with data
std::vector<std::vector<int> > mod;

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
   mod.push_back(vector<int>(data[i].begin(), data[i].end()));
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Too bad `mod` can't be `std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>> mod;` and then just `mod.push_back({data[i].begin(), data[i].end()});`

Comment: You should certainly add `mod.reserve(data.size());` before your for loop to prevent reallocation of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be more efficient

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2> > data; // filled with data
std::vector<std::vector<int> > mod;

mod.reserve(data.size());
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
   mod.emplace_back(data[i].begin(), data[i].end());
}
```

`reserve` prevents reallocation of the `mod` vector as it grows, and `emplace_back` constructs the smaller vectors in place, potentially avoiding some copying of data.